# What's the correct way to determine the size of an SVG in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

Just as the title says: what's the correct way to determine the size (width, height) of an SVG element in Internet Explorer?

Most browsers seem to support `.offsetWidth` and `.offsetHeight`, but this doesn't appear to work in IE (tested with IE 10).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c7eqe/1/ (on IE, this shows "offsetWidth: undefined")

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get size of SVG graphics by javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231679/get-size-of-svg-graphics-by-javascript)

Comment: This doesn't work on Internet Explorer; `svg.contentDocument` is undefined.

Comment: I noticed that myself in Chrome. That's why I deleted my answer. Still looks to be a dupe though.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, it seems like the `getBoundingClientRect()` is (supposed to be) supported by all the major browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect

```
>> svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0]
>> svg.getBoundingClientRect()
[object ClientRect] {
    bottom : 590,
    height : 400,
    left : 199,
    right : 1009,
    top : 190,
    width : 810
>>
```